# How can I create custom URL to support handles for users.

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am having a website where I have a URL like 
xyz.com/abc.jsp?user=5

Now if this user with id 5 ; wants to create a handle like deepakagra so that he can access his profile by xyz.com/deepakagra ; how can i achieve it ?

I am using jsp, servlet on tomcat.

Comment: you need a front controller that get url and parse it then forward it to new page >>>>>> /abc.jsp?user=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctely, you don't want to use parameters in GET.
when you hit localhost:8080/profile/deepakagra, it should call this servlet if it's mapped to the pattern

```
@WebServlet(name="profile", urlPatterns={"/profile/*"} )
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet { 
....

protected final String getProfileId(HttpServletRequest request ){
        String base = request.getPathInfo();
        String id = null ;
        if( base.split("/").length >= 2 )
          id = base.split("/")[1] ;
        return id ;
      }
```

Then in your GET/POST method you call getProfileId and obtian the ID. You pull it from the DB, do the processing you need, and forward to JSP.

Note: this code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to parse 'deepakagra' as a GET parameter to the page, then do a database lookup to find the ID for that username and grab the contents you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have servlet, you can always create servlet and define servlet-mapping in web.xml as "deepakagra" and that will forward your request to abc.jsp.

Comment: There can be hundreds of users; and these users are generated on runtime as website grows users gets created automatically

Answer (score 0):

I used urlrewrite by tuckey. Here we can easily create a rule which will achieve above.